# table view delegate methods not all called

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

In my code I'm using a tableview for which some of the methods are getting called, while others are not.

in initwithframe:

```
_table.delegate = self;
_table.dataSource = self;
```

this is called

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"TRAutocompleteCell";

    id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [_cellFactory createReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    NSLog(@"got here 3");

    NSAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]], @"Cell must inherit from UITableViewCell");
    NSAssert([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TRAutocompletionCell)], @"Cell must conform TRAutocompletionCell");
    UITableViewCell <TRAutocompletionCell> *completionCell = (UITableViewCell <TRAutocompletionCell> *) cell;

    id suggestion = self.suggestions[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    NSAssert([suggestion conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TRSuggestionItem)], @"Suggestion item must conform TRSuggestionItem");
    id <TRSuggestionItem> suggestionItem = (id <TRSuggestionItem>) suggestion;

    [completionCell updateWith:suggestionItem];

    return cell;
}
```

but this is not getting called in the same file.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"got here 5");
    id suggestion = self.suggestions[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"got here 4");
    NSAssert([suggestion conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TRSuggestionItem)], @"Suggestion item must conform TRSuggestionItem");

    self.selectedSuggestion = (id <TRSuggestionItem>) suggestion;

    _queryTextField.text = self.selectedSuggestion.completionText;
    [_queryTextField resignFirstResponder];

    if (self.didAutocompleteWith)
        self.didAutocompleteWith(self.selectedSuggestion);

}
```

Comment: are yuo sure, you have hooked table with UITableView?

Comment: From what you have written it seems that the problem is with the UITableViewDelegate. Are you sure you are implementing the protocol ?

Comment: in .h file add this one UITableViewDelegate

Comment: @pe60t0: in new compilers it is not required at all.

Comment: yes, I have them: @interface TRAutocompleteView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>. still its not called. I really dont understand how this is possible

Comment: are you implementing this method `-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?, if you are, are you returning a not `nil` value from there?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : Hi, which compilers exactly are you referring to ?

Comment: one coming with xcode4.4 and above....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the implementation, but my gesture recognition.

I have added a lister to my view to catch the tap event outside my text box, which was being called. I do not exactly know why these two are clashing, but when I removed it, it was working.

The tableview is for autocompletion in my textbox.

Answer (score -1):

Did You do:

```
yourTableView.delegate = self;
yourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

While creating the tableView.

If it is .xib file , did you connect the delegate and dataSource?